# Zeros-one trick for Bayesian Generalized Poisson using JAGS

Tags: r, glm, jags

I am fitting count data to Generalized Poisson distribution in JAGS,using the zeros-ones trick. I am following codes in the "Bayesian Modeling Using WinBUGS" book(page 286).Here are my codes:

```
GPoisson.model <- function(){
C <- 10000
for(i in 1:N){
    zeros[i] <- 0
    zeros[i] ~ dpois(zeros.mean[i])
    zeros.mean[i] <- -l[i] + C
    #log-likelihood 
    lambda.star[i] <- (1-omega)*lambda[i] + omega*y[i]
    l[i] <- log((1-omega)*lambda[i]) + (y[i]-1)*log(lambda.star[i]) -
    loggam(y[i]+1) - lambda[i]
    #log-link + linear predictor
    log(lambda[i]) <- log(E[i]) + inprod(X[i,],beta[])
    }
#priors
omega ~ dbeta(1,1)
for(j in 1:17){
    beta[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
}
```

}

When I run the model I got this error:

```
Compilation error on line 6.
Attempt to redefine node zeros[1]
```

I still don't understand what is wrong with zeros[i]. Enlighten me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lines

```
     zeros[i] <- 0
     zeros[i] ~ dpois(zeros.mean[i])
```

cause a problem. In JAGS you can't redefine the given value of a variable. I think you should drop the line:

```
 zeros[i] <- 0
```

from your code

Comment: Yes,I dropped `zeros[i] <- 0` and in the end the codes are as below:

`data {
 for(i in 1:N){
  zeros[i] <- 0
 }
}
model{
 
 C <- 1000
 for(i in 1:N) {
  zeros[i] ~ dpois(zeros.mean[i])  
  zeros.mean[i] <- -l[i] + C
  #log-likelihood 
  lambda.star[i] <- (1-omega)*lambda[i] + omega*y[i]
  l[i] <- log((1-omega)*lambda[i]) + (y[i]-1)*log(lambda.star[i]) -
  loggam(y[i]+1) - lambda.star[i]
  #log-link + linear predictor
  lambda[i] <- E[i]*exp(inprod(X[i,],beta[])) 
 }
 #priors
 omega ~ dunif(0,1) 
 for(j in 1:17){
  beta[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
 }
}"
`